# Assigning many values from one object to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, parallel-processing, each

I am trying to write a ruby function that iterates through an array of strings that are method names and uses the  `Object#send` method to save values in a new instance object (not even sure if thats legit) that is a transformation of an already existing one. That's the best I can explain it. Here's the idea:

```
@example = RelatedClass.new

def example_method
  instance_dependant_float = related_class.myvalue / other_related_class.myvalue

  ARRAY_OF_METHODS.each do |t|
    @example.send(t+'=', self.related_class.t * instance_dependant_float)
  end
end
```

When I try to run something like this where I call the index "t" on two separate ocassions (in my send and in the multiplier) it NoMethodError's on the second ocassion.

Comment: 1) What's `ARRAY_OF_METHODS`? 2) Is `related_class` the same as `RelatedClass`? 3) How is this parallel iteration?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm 1) _"an array of strings that are method names"_. 2) Good question for perhaps finding a better solution, but unrelated to the `NoMethodError`. 3) It's not; I've edited the title to match. :)

Comment: Yeah, I botched that up badly. Thank you Phrogz, you understood perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `send` to get the value also:

```
ARRAY_OF_METHODS.each do |name|
   @example.send( :"#{name}=", related_class.send(name) * some_float )
end
```

*I always use and advocate string interpolation over `String#+`, and you don't need the `self.` to get the `related_class`.*

Comment: Ah thanks so much Phrogz for your solution and interpretation of my blabber! Worked perfectly!